# Get address of the breakpoint in Lauterbach

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

On setting breakpoint using the command,
Break.set function

And the breakpoint is set at the start of the function. We want to get the address of the breakpoint.

How can we get the address of the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

`Break.List` opens a window which shows all breakpoints

`sYmbol.RANGE(<symbol>)` can be used to get the address (range) of a symbol, e.g.

```
AREA
PRINT sYmbol.RANGE(<symbol>)
```

Comment: Thanks, we were able to print the address range of a function. We are working with Python, to automate the test. We are able to keep breakpoint in a particular line of code in a file using, t32api.T32_Cmd("Break.Set func+20'")or , t32api.T32_Cmd("Break.Set func\0+4"). Is it possible to get the address of the breakpoint in a variable?  We are trying to verify the breakpoint address that is currently set with the address in the program pointer.